# How do I render the 'user_picture' of a user account?

Tags: 8, users

I load a user object, and I would like to be able to show the user's picture somewhere. I tried the following code.

```
$row_user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid)->user_picture->first()->view('large');
```

What I get is this (using `kint()`).

[image: the user_picture]

This user has a picture and it is shown correctly in the user page.

How do I exactly show the picture associated with a user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like every other render array, render it.

If you print it out in twig, that just works, in PHP, use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->render()`.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why `#url => NULL` because I would like to get the URL to the image.

Comment: large is a user view mode, not an image style. You can create and configure the field there to show a link. Or pass an array with configuration to it, same structure as stored in view displays